# About mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

```
    id  |   name    |   salary  
--------------------------------
    1   |    A      |   100   
    1   |    A      |   200
```

this in my table ,and I want out put as below. (Here  salary type is integer)

```
    id  |   name    |   salary  
--------------------------------
    1   |    A      |   100/200
```

Comment: such simple question. Have you even tried googling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select
  id,
  name,
  group_concat(salary SEPARATOR '/') as salaries
from tableName
group by id
```

Comment: in my table  salary is integer.when I executed above query, in salaries  field no value is there..

Comment: @user2709752: group by should be on `id` but not on `salary`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
    sno,
    name, 
    group_concat(CAST(salary AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '/') as salaries
From mytable
Group by sno;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should go for group concat on column name check this [link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Group_Concat](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)

Try like this

```
Select id,name, group_concat(salary SEPARATOR '/') as salaries 
From table1
Group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**GROUP_CONCAT(expr)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
  id,
  `name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(salary SEPARATOR '/') AS salary 
FROM
  `table` 
GROUP BY id
```

**Note Be aware of that the result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable, which has a default value of 1024**